# Merge two data with respect to date and week using R

Tags: r, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have two data. One has a `year_month_week` column and the other has a `date` column. I simplified and made two data for demonstration purpose.

```
df1<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
               year_month_week=c(2022051,2022052,2022053,2022041,2022042,2022043,2022044),
               points=c(65,58,47,21,25,27,43))

df2<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                date=c(20220503,20220506,20220512,20220401,20220408,20220409),
                temperature=c(36.1,36.3,36.6,34.3,34.9,35.3))
```

For `df1`, `2022051` means 1st week of May,2022. Likewise, `2022052` means 2nd week of May,2022. For `df2`,`20220503` means May 3rd, 2022.
What I want to do now is merge `df1` and `df2` with respect to `year_month_week`. In this case, `20220503` and `20220506` are 1st week of May,2022. If more than one `date` are in `year_month_week`, I will just include the first of them. So my expected output is as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2),
               year_month_week=c(2022051,2022052,2022041,2022042),
               points=c(65,58,21,25),
               temperature=c(36.1,36.6,34.3,34.9))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to extract the last two digits of your `date` column in `df2`, divide the digits by 7, then round them up. This would be your `week` number (this part is in the `mutate` function).

Then just `group_by` the `year_month_week` column and only output one record per `year_month_week`, and join with `df1`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(year_month_week = 
           as.integer(
             paste0(str_extract(df2$date, ".*(?=\\d\\d$)"),
                    ceiling(as.integer(str_extract(df2$date, "\\d\\d$"))/7))
             )) %>% 
  group_by(year_month_week) %>% 
  slice_min(date) %>% 
  left_join(df1,
            by = c("year_month_week", "id")) %>% 
  select(-date)

df
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   year_month_week [4]
     id temperature year_month_week points
  <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2        34.3         2022041     21
2     2        34.9         2022042     25
3     1        36.1         2022051     65
4     1        36.6         2022052     58
```