# Aggregate week and date in R by some specific rules

Tags: r, datetime, merge, week-number

I'm not used to using R. I already asked a question on stack overflow and got a great answer.
I'm sorry to post a similar question, but I tried many times and got the output that I didn't expect.
This time, I want to do slightly different from my previous question.
[Merge two data with respect to date and week using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73111233/merge-two-data-with-respect-to-date-and-week-using-r)
I have two data. One has a year_month_week column and the other has a date column.

```
df1<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
               year_month_week=c(2022051,2022052,2022053,2022041,2022042,2022043,2022044),
               points=c(65,58,47,21,25,27,43))

df2<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                date=c(20220503,20220506,20220512,20220401,20220408,20220409),
                temperature=c(36.1,36.3,36.6,34.3,34.9,35.3))
```

For df1, 2022051 means 1st week of May,2022. Likewise, 2022052 means 2nd week of May,2022. For df2,20220503 means May 3rd, 2022. What I want to do now is merge df1 and df2 with respect to year_month_week. In this case, 20220503 and 20220506 are 1st week of May,2022.If more than one date are in year_month_week, I will just include the first of them. Now, here's the different part. Even if there is no `date` inside `year_month_week`,just leave it `NA`. So my expected output has a same number of rows as `df1` which includes the column `year_month_week`.So my expected output is as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
               year_month_week=c(2022051,2022052,2022053,2022041,2022042,2022043,2022044),
               points=c(65,58,47,21,25,27,43),
               temperature=c(36.1,36.6,NA,34.3,34.9,NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we can convert the dates in `df2` into year-month-date format, then join the two tables:

```
library(dplyr);library(lubridate)
df2$dt = ymd(df2$date)
df2$wk = day(df2$dt) %/% 7 + 1
df2$year_month_week = as.numeric(paste0(format(df2$dt, "%Y%m"), df2$wk))

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% group_by(year_month_week) %>% slice(1) %>%
              select(year_month_week, temperature))
```

Result

```
Joining, by = "year_month_week"
  id year_month_week points temperature
1  1         2022051     65        36.1
2  1         2022052     58        36.6
3  1         2022053     47          NA
4  2         2022041     21        34.3
5  2         2022042     25        34.9
6  2         2022043     27          NA
7  2         2022044     43          NA
```

Comment: In my actual dataset, there are lots of columns in `df1` and `df2` , so I cannot use the code you suggested. Is there any way to change the last code ```select(year_month_week, temperature)```? I cannot write the column name `temperature` explicitly. I wonder if I can insert the position of the column inside `select`.

Comment: You could drop the `select` line if you don't mind having those extra helper columns. If there are common column names with distinct data in the two tables which you want to keep, you might need to add `by = "year_month_week"` into your `left_join`.

Answer (score 1):

You can build off of a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199851/r-how-to-get-the-week-number-of-the-month) by taking the function to count the week of the month, then generate a join key in df2. See here

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  year_month_week=c(2022051,2022052,2022053,2022041,2022042,2022043,2022044),
  points=c(65,58,47,21,25,27,43))

df2 <- data.frame(
  id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  date=c(20220503,20220506,20220512,20220401,20220408,20220409),
  temperature=c(36.1,36.3,36.6,34.3,34.9,35.3))

# Take the function from the previous StackOverflow question
monthweeks.Date <- function(x) {
  ceiling(as.numeric(format(x, "%d")) / 7)
}

# Create a year_month_week variable to join on 
df2 <- 
  df2 %>%
  mutate(
    date = lubridate::parse_date_time(
      x = date, 
      orders = "%Y%m%d"),
    year_month_week = paste0(
      lubridate::year(date), 
      0,
      lubridate::month(date),
      monthweeks.Date(date)),
    year_month_week = as.double(year_month_week)) 

# Remove duplicate year_month_weeks
df2 <- 
  df2 %>%
  arrange(year_month_week) %>% 
  distinct(year_month_week, .keep_all = T)

# Join dataframes
df1 <- 
  left_join(
    df1, 
    df2, 
    by = "year_month_week")
```

Produces this result

```
id.x year_month_week points id.y       date temperature
1    1         2022051     65    1 2022-05-03        36.1
2    1         2022052     58    1 2022-05-12        36.6
3    1         2022053     47   NA       <NA>          NA
4    2         2022041     21    2 2022-04-01        34.3
5    2         2022042     25    2 2022-04-08        34.9
6    2         2022043     27   NA       <NA>          NA
7    2         2022044     43   NA       <NA>          NA
>
```

Edit: forgot to mention that you need tidyverse loaded

```
library(tidyverse)
```